# \tableheadline within foreach

Tags: tabularx, foreach, pgffor

I want to generate a list of column headings in a `tabularx` automatically. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

%Adopted from classicthesis-config.tex
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\def\coauthors{{John}, {Sue}, {Terry}}

%Adopted from https://texwelt.de/fragen/22216/pgffor-tabelleninhalt-mit-foreach-erzeugen
\makeatletter
\xdef\coauthorheadline{}%
\foreach \coauthor in \coauthors%
{%
  \protected@xdef\coauthorheadline{\coauthorheadline%
    \coauthor \protect&}%
}
\makeatother

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c|c|c} %TODO: Remove extraneous column at the end due to superfluous & above
    \coauthorheadline \\
    %TODO: Rest
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This works fine if I do not use any formatting within my `foreach`. However, if I add `\tableheadline`, in particular, LaTeX complains. Instead of

```
\coauthor \protect&}%
```

above I tried

```
\tableheadline{\coauthor} \protect&}%
```

as well as

```
\protect{\tableheadline{\coauthor}} \protect&}%
```

Unfortunately, both do not work. How can I delay the expansion of the `\tableheadline` command just long enough for `tabularx` to execute it?

Comment: How is `\tableheadline` defined?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: I thought it is defined in `tabularx`. My original document uses `classicthesis`.

Comment: I do not think it is defined in either of these packages. Can you add a definition to your code?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: It seems to have been defined in the default configuration file of `classicthesis`. I added it to the code above.

Comment: Great. Now I get `> \spacedlowsmallcaps=undefined.
l.6 \show\spacedlowsmallcap`. Can't you just post an example that in principle works?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: It's very hard to make a MWE without the `classicthesis` files. I was not aware that these definitions are defined in additional dependencies. The problem persists if `\textbf` is used instead, so I modified it above.

Comment: `\multicolumn` has to come immediately at the beginning of a cell, but after expanding `\coauthorsheadline`, you have `\protect\tableheadline`, i.e., `\protect\multicolumn` there. Without `\protect`, it obviously fails for other reasons (`\tableheadline` expands too early). If you remove `\multicolumn` from the definition of `\tableheadline`, then it works.

Comment: Generating the table on this level is fragile (and full of frustrations, if one does not understand the inner workings of TeX, and of tabulars in particular; I don't ...). Maybe take a step back, describe what you want to achieve (in another posting), and let's see how this can be done, with or without tabulars. E.g., my solution to tables generated flexibly from data often is to generate the lines myself (with the width of cells controlled by my code). By having such lines below each other, you obtain a table that even breaks across pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gernot's comments are about right, except that I don't think there would ever be `\protect\multicolumn` in the input stream. `\protect` acts on the next token; it should *not* be followed by a braced argument. So, the `\protect{\tableheadline{\coauthor}}` code fragment in the question is an incorrect use of `\protect`. `\protect\tableheadline` would be a correct use, but this would prevent `\multicolumn` from doing its work. Indeed, in order to work, commands such as `\multicolumn` or `\rowcolor` must not come after an unexpandable, non-space token in a given cell (line in the case of `\rowcolor`). `\protect` would prevent this, AFAIK, because during normal typesetting, it is `\let`-equal to `\relax` due to this definition:

```latex
\let\@typeset@protect\relax
```

(and `\relax` is unexpandable). The good news is that there is a solution. :-) You just need to make sure that you generate the material in an expandable way, so that nothing gets in the way of `\multicolumn` when TeX recursively expands tokens at the beginning of the row, looking for `\noalign` or `\omit`.

Note that I gave the last column the `X` type, because a `tabularx` without an `X` column doesn't make much sense.

```latex
\documentclass{article} % no problem with memoir either
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{#1}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g__andreas_coauthors_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \coauthors { m }
  {
    % Comment out the following line if you want to append to the list of
    % coauthors instead of replacing it.
    \seq_gclear:N \g__andreas_coauthors_seq
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
      { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__andreas_coauthors_seq { \tableheadline {##1} } }
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \coauthorheadline { }
  {
    \seq_use:Nn \g__andreas_coauthors_seq { & }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% You can do this in the preamble if you prefer, but babel catcodes may not be
% set up yet, in this case.
\coauthors{{John}, {Sue}, {Terry}}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|c|c|X}
  \coauthorheadline \\
  Foo foo foo & bar bar bar & baz baz baz & \lipsum[1][1-2] \\
  a           & b           & c           & d.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Note: this works well with `\multicolumn` because `\seq_use:Nn` is fully expandable (it is documented with a full star in the margin in [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf)). When TeX recursively expands `\coauthorheadline` at the beginning of the first row of the `tabularx`, it doesn't encounter any unexpandable, non-space token before arriving at `\multicolumn`.